# after data creation by modal, it doesn't display index razor view

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1. I'm using the following link  https://www.codaffection.com/asp-net-core-article/jquery-ajax-crud-in-asp-net-core-mvc/ to implement create operation with showing a modal after selecting the related button in razor view. Now after the user clicks on the "New" button a modal pops up and after filling the item fields on it and clicking on save button, the web should show _ViewAll which shows all the records in a dataTable. But right now it shows a white page and only after refreshing the page and displaying _ViewAll, I can see that data is saved and the dataTable shows it. By tracing my code I can see in AddOrEditHelper class, the sw property shows {}. I'm sure the problem is about this property that doesn't get data in it. I appreciate if anyone could suggests me a solution for it.

Here below is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit(int id, ItemRequesterViewModel ItemRequesterViewModel)
    {
        var lastchangesDate = PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd").PersianToEnglish();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Insert
            if (id == 0)
            {

                _context.Set<Itemrequester>().Add(new Itemrequester
                {

                    Itemid = ItemRequesterViewModel.Itemrequestervm.Itemid,
                    GateId = ItemRequesterViewModel.Itemrequestervm.GateId,
                    RequesterId = ItemRequesterViewModel.Itemrequestervm.RequesterId,
                    ItemRequestDate = ItemRequesterViewModel.Itemrequestervm.ItemRequestDate,
                    ItemRequestNo = ItemRequesterViewModel.Itemrequestervm.ItemRequestNo,

                    Description = ItemRequesterViewModel.Itemrequestervm.Description,
                   
                });


                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                var myItemrequesterId = (from x in _context.Itemrequester
                                        where x.ItemRequestNo == ItemRequesterViewModel.Itemrequestervm.ItemRequestNo
                                        select new { x.Id }
                             ).First();





                var myresult = _context.Itemrequester.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == myItemrequesterId.Id);
                if (myresult != null)
                {
                    myresult.LastRequestStatus = 2021;
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
              
            }
         
           
       return Json(new { isValid = true, html = 
Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "_ViewAll", 
 _context.VwReport.AsQueryable().Where(a => 
 a.IsDeleted.Equals(false)).ToList())});
        }
        return Json(new { isValid = false, html = 
 Helper.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "AddOrEdit", ItemRequesterViewModel) 
});
    }







    //==============================================
    public class ItemRequesterViewModel
    {
    public ItemRequester ItemRequestervm { get; set; }
    public VwReport ItemRequesterVwReport { get; set; }
    public ItemRequesterHistory ItemRequesterHistoryvm { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

}
```

//==========================================================================================================

```
public partial class ItemRequester
{
    public ItemRequester()
    {
        ItemRequesterHistory = new HashSet<ItemRequesterHistory>();
    }


    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? Itemid { get; set; }
    public int? RequesterId { get; set; }
    public int? GateId { get; set; }
    public int? LastRequestStatus { get; set; }
    public string ItemRequestDate { get; set; }
    public int? ItemRequestNo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }


    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    public virtual Requester Requester { get; set; }
    public virtual Gate Gate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemRequesterHistory> ItemRequesterHistory { get; set; }
}
 ///----------------------------------------------------------------------

public partial class VwReport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? RequesterId { get; set; }
    public string RequesterName { get; set; }
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }

 
    public string ItemRequestDate { get; set; }
  
    public int? ItemRequestNo { get; set; }
    public int? LastRequestStatus { get; set; }

}
```

//========================================================================

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.VwReport>


        
        <a onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Itemrequesters",null,Context.Request.Scheme)','New Request')" class="btn btn-success text-white"><i class="fas fa-random"></i> New Request</a>

  <script>
  var selectedIds = [];
  var descriptionText = "";

  var oTable;
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#myDummyTable").DataTable({


            'columnDefs': [
                {
                    'targets': 0,
                    "searching": false,
                    'checkboxes': {
                        'selectRow': true
                    }
                }
           
            ],
            'select': {
                'style': 'multi',
                'selector': 'td:first-child'
            },
            'order': [[1, 'asc']],

            "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        });

   });



jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    oTable = $("#myDummyTable").dataTable();

            $("input[name='hiddeninput']").val(selectedIds);

            
    
                $('#showDataModal').modal('show');
           
            //});

            //$('#showDataModal').modal('show');
        });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      $("#exitbutton").click(function () {
        selectedIds = [];          //You must clear the selectedIds and close 
    the modal when exit, or duplicate value will be passed
        $('#showDataModal').modal('toggle');
      });
    });

  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   

    $("#deletethem").click(function () {
       
    var descContent=$.trim($("#descId").val());
  $.ajax({
    url: "Itemrequesters/selectedListOperation",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    cache: false,                  /*descriptionText*/
    data: { "Id": selectedIds, "description": descContent },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("");
    }
   });
  });
  });

  </script>






 @*************************************@
//Here below in _ViewAll

 @model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.VwReport>


     

    <a 
 onclick="showInPopup('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Itemrequesters",null,Context.Reqe 
    st.Scheme)','New Request')" class="btn btn-success text-white"><i class="fas 
    fa-random"></i> New Request</a>

   <script>
   var selectedIds = [];
   var descriptionText = "";

    var oTable;
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#myDummyTable").DataTable({


            'columnDefs': [
                {
                    'targets': 0,
                    "searching": false,
                    'checkboxes': {
                        'selectRow': true
                    }
                }
           
            ],
            'select': {
                'style': 'multi',
                'selector': 'td:first-child'
            },
            'order': [[1, 'asc']],

            "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        });

   });


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    oTable = $("#myDummyTable").dataTable();

   
});



 </script>


<div class="my-5 col-sm-12 p-4">
<table id="myDummyTable">
    <thead>
        <tr id="headerrow">
            <th>

            </th>
            <th hidden>
                ID
            </th>
            <th>
                ItemRequestNumber
            </th>
            <th>
                Requester
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </td>
                <td hidden>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApiRequestNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequesterName)
                </td>
               
              
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>


$('#request_layout').css({ "background-color": "rgb(50, 149, 155)" });
</script>
}


 //----------------------------------
   //The code in site.js

    showInPopup = (url, title) => {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function (res) {
             $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res);
             $('#form-modal .modal-title').html(title);
             $('#form-modal').modal('show');
         }
       })
      }

    jQueryAjaxPost = form => {
    try {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.action,
        data: new FormData(form),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (res) {
            if (res.isValid) {
                $('#view-all').html(res.html)
                $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
                $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
                $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
            }
            else
                $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
      })
       //to prevent default form submit event
       return false;
   } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex)
    }
   }

  //And my modal definition is in _Layout like in the link
```

Comment: It could be the error of javascript, can you share the code from github, because I can run correctly on local machine.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. After using F12 in the browser, I don't see any error or warning message. So I don't think the problem's cause is relative to the javascript. Also I set breakpoint in my code and I understood the problem is  in Helper class, although the input parameters are sent as the method's arguments RenderRazorViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model = null) in Helper class, However, I see after step by step tracing the code, inside the method RenderRazorViewToString, sw parameter shows me {}

Answer (score 1):

If it needs you to manually reload the page, you can as well reload the page using your jQuery code by adding

`window.location.href = res.html`

In your function.
In your case, this will work

`

```
jQueryAjaxPost = form => {
    try {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.action,
        data: new FormData(form),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (res) {
            if (res.isValid) {
                $('#view-all').html(res.html)
                $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
                $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
                $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
                window.location.href = res.html
            }
            else
                $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
      })
       //to prevent default form submit event
       return false;
   } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex)
    }
   }
```

`